# Windows Azure App Service running a NET Core 7 App with with MassTransit running a "jar" file, HOW?

Tags: java, .net, azure

So, we have a .NET Core 7 MassTransit host running in a Azure App Service and one of the command handlers should make a "**java.exe -jar DoSomeThing.jar**" call. Our question is, how can we make this work in the App Service?

- Installing Java SDK somehow when deploying the app?
- Copying the Java SDK as embedded files in a folder (as we do with the .jar)
- Embedding the SDK with the .jar (don't really know if this is even possible)
- Any other suggestion

Creating a Java App Service is not a good solution for us, as MassTransit handlers are managing this calls and retrieving the results. Any suggestion will be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It is not possible to mix different runtime stacks in a single App Service instance directly.

> Creating a Java App Service is not a good solution for us.

- As following to the condition without creating a separate app service we can containerize both the .NET Core and Java applications using Docker container. You can package the .NET Core 7 Mass Transit host and the Java executable (DoSomeThing.jar) into a single container, check the template below.

```
# Set the base image to a Linux distribution that supports both .NET Core and Java
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0-jdk11

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the .NET Core project files to the container
COPY MyMassTransitHost.csproj .

# Restore the .NET Core dependencies
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy the entire project to the container
COPY . .

# Build the .NET Core application
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Copy the Java application (DoSomeThing.jar) to the container
COPY DoSomeThing.jar .

# Set the entry point to start both the .NET Core MassTransit Host and the Java application
CMD ["sh", "-c", "dotnet /app/out/MyMassTransitHost.dll & java -jar /app/DoSomeThing.jar"]
```

- Push the Docker Image to a Container Registry. while creating app service in the portal the runtime can be .Net and publish should be Docker container.

[image]

- Deploy the .NET Core App Service using the custom Docker image.
- Once your .NET Core App Service is running with the custom Docker image, update your MassTransit command handler to execute the Java command.

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;

public class MyCommandHandler
{
    public void HandleCommand()
    {
        // Replace "/path/to/java" with the appropriate path to the Java executable in the container
        string javaExecutable = "/path/to/java";
        
        // Replace "/app/DoSomeThing.jar" with the actual path to the JAR file inside the container
        string jarFile = "/app/DoSomeThing.jar";
        
        // Replace "YourJavaOptions" with any additional Java options you want to pass
        string javaOptions = "YourJavaOptions";
        
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = javaExecutable,
            Arguments = $"{javaOptions} -jar {jarFile}",
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };
        
        using (Process process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
            
            // You can optionally read the process output if needed
            string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
}
```

By this we able to execute the Java JAR file directly within the same App Service.

Comment: Sounds good. Thank you! Any chance I can do something similar without a Docker container? Just publishing my .NET app from DevOps embedding the Java SDK in the package?

Comment: @XavierCasals, there is no other approach other than containerizing as I mentioned in the answer.